# SQL Server Debugging: "Unable to Step. Invalid operation"

Tags: sql-server, ssms, debugging, sql-server-2012

I'm debugging a call to a Stored Procedure in SSMS (2012). Frequently, and various random points in the code, a dialog pops up:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:
Unable to Step. Invalid Operation.
```

Once I dismiss the dialog, it appears that debugging CAN continue... I can continue to step through the code to the end, without any apparent problems. So far....

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @IanW I'm afraid I didn't find a solution at the time, and I've actually moved on from that role now.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. After some research I found [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2008/06/07/getting-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-a-retry-should-be-performed-while-debugging-in-visual-studio.aspx) which suggests that this is caused by a race condition. Although the workaround given there wasn't applicable for me, after stopping every other debugging processes (Visual Studio) these annoying error messages didn't display anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I finally know why I get this error on every version of SQL Server - it's because I usually have Visual Studio running, and I'm debugging something in VS, and then I go to debug one of the stored procedures. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Please upvote this issue if you experience it too:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3068631/sql-2016-debug-gets-unable-to-step-invalid-operation-error-when-debugging